# Could not find installable ISAM with Excel

Tags: windows, oledb, oledbconnection

Here's my connection string:

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\clnts\Symphony.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=No;IMEX=1;';"
```

I get "Cannot find installable ISAM" at Connection.Open

I've tried every combination of quotes/single quotes that fixed it for other people on this site, but it still doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Try replacing the Provider with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; for Excel 12.0

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that and I get The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: No - check again - if you got 4.0 in that message the string wasn't quite right...

Comment: I just ran it again using this connection string:

 Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\clnts\Symphony.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=No;IMEX=1;';"

and got this error:

 The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I also installed the 32 bit version of Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable and got the same result. I then did the same with the 64 bit version but wasn't able to install it, seemingly because I have Office 365.

Comment: Again try "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" **Check that 12**. The reason you are getting the error you are seeing now is there is no Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.*4.0*

Comment: Oh I see. LOL. Thanks, that was it! Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: No problem! I've been there many times and knew what you were facing. Forest and trees, as they say! LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 as the provider solves the problem.